# list Azure websites using Azure service management API

Tags: api, azure, azure-web-app-service

I am looking to monitor my Azure account programmatically.
Going through the MS Azure Service management API, i have found a way to identify virtual machines and cloud services. but i can't seem to find a way to list machines under the azure websites service.

can anyone help with this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the code used in the [PowerShell cmdlets](https://github.com/WindowsAzure/azure-sdk-tools/tree/master/WindowsAzurePowershell/src/Management.WebSites/Services). The [UriElements.cs](https://github.com/WindowsAzure/azure-sdk-tools/blob/master/WindowsAzurePowershell/src/Management.WebSites/Utilities/UriElements.cs) file can also give you extra information regarding the urls you should use.

Comment: The links provided does not exist anymore. Can you please share updated one.
Thanks